# Creating resource reference ints programmatically

Tags: android, string, reference

I am building a quiz app with questions in a string resource, as well as an answer. They are formatted by numbers like so:

```
<string name="ques1">What color is the sky?</string>
<string name="ques2">What sound does a cow make?</string>
```

The answers are also strings corresponding to the same number as the questions:

```
<string name="ans1">Blue</string>
<string name="ans2">Moo</string>
```

I have created a QA class for holding both a question and the answer, as well as the user's response from an EditText. At the "loading" of my app these classes are created and filled by reading from the strings resource.

I can programmatically enter these no problem, it is a lot of copy pasting but it will get the job done:

```
QA.setQuestion(getString(R.string.ques1));
QA.setAnswer(getString(R.string.ans1));
quizList.add(QA);
QA.setQuestion(getString(R.string.ques2));
QA.setAnswer(getString(R.string.ans2));
quizList.add(QA);
etc...
```

The problem is that I want to be able to add questions and answers to the xml at any time without having to add yet another repetition of the above method. What I want to do is essentially this:

```
String refBase = "R.string."
String ans = "ans"; 
String ques = "ques";
int numOfQues = 25; //only change when questions are added or removed

for (int i = 0; i < numOfQues; i++)
    {
        String referenceQ = refBase + ques + i;
        String referenceA = refBase + ans + i;
        QA.setQuestion(getString(referenceQ));
        QA.setAnswer(getString(referenceA));
        quizList.add(QA);
    }
```

I cannot cast a string to an int like this obviously, but I am wondering if there is a way to implement a reference "builder", where I don't have to repeat many lines of code just to read another string with the same name but incremented number.

I understand that I can also just create an array.xml with one for questions and one for answers, making sure their position in each array corresponds. This would be easiest I think, but I guess I am wondering if it is possible to create references to string values through the code like my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method to get the question or answer String by its resource name:

```
    String getQAString(boolean isQuestion, int index) {
        String prefix = isQuestion? "ques" : "ans";
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(prefix + index, "string", getPackageName());
        return resId != 0? getString(resId) : "";
    }
```

The loop to add questions and answers (assume they start from 1 and end at 25):

```
    int numOfQues = 25;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfQues; i++) {
        String referenceQ = getQAString(true, i);
        String referenceA = getQAString(false, i);
        QA.setQuestion(referenceQ);
        QA.setAnswer(referenceA);
        quizList.add(QA);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer I was looking for!